# ¿Como comparo en un bucle for un elemento con el anterior o el siguiente sin que salte el error "list index out of range"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

```py
lista=[3,2,5,9]
for x in lista:
    if lista[x] > lista[x+1]: 
            print(x)
```

Esta es la linea del código que me dio problemas y estos son los intentos de soluciones.

El primer intento:

```py
lista=[3,2,5,9]
for x in lista:
    try:
        if lista[x] > lista[x+1]: 
            print(x)
    except:
        continue
```

El segundo intento:

```py
lista=[3,2,5,9]
c=0
for x in lista:
    if c >0:
        if lista[x] > lista[x+1]: 
            print(x)
    c=c+1
```

Comment: Ahí `x` esta tomando los valores de tu lista, osea `x` en la primera iteracion valdrá `3` y al hacer `lista[3]` saldrá `5`, pero es en la tercera iteracion donde se provoca el error, por que `lista[5]` no existe. Quita ese `if` y en vez, de usar `x` usa `c`

Comment: Si, es algo que ya lo sabia, entiendo el porque del error, pero lo que no se es como conseguir lo que quiero evitandolo: Imprimir los valores de la lista teniendo en cuenta los valores próximos a el.

Comment: y porque no utlizas la funcion reduce?

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un par de errores de concepto.

**Primer error**. Al iterar con la sintaxis `for x in lista` la variable `x` va tomando los **valores** contenidos en la lista. Es decir, en tu caso `x` pasará por los valores 3, 2, 5 y 9. Cuando dentro del bucle intentas `lista[x]` eso dará lugar respectivamente a `lista[3]`, `lista[2]`,  `lista[5]` y `lista[9]`. Pero no es eso lo que quieres hacer, ya que `lista[3]` significa "acceder al elemento que ocupa la posición 3 dentro de la lista" (en este caso sería el 9), y no "el elemento de valor 3". Y lo que es peor, `lista[5]` ya no existe pues los índices sólo pueden ir entre 0 y 3.

Supongo por tanto que lo que pretendes es que la `x` vaya tomando los valores 0, 1, 2 y 3 en vez de 3, 2, 5 y 9. Para eso no debes usar `for x in lista`, sino `for x in range(4)` o más generalmente `for x in range(len(lista))`.

Eso nos lleva al **segundo problema** y es que cuando `x` alcance el último de esos valores (3), al intentar compararlo con `lista[x+1]` estarás intentando acceder a un elemento 4 que ya no existe.

Parece que en tu segundo enfoque intentas corregir esos problemas, al introducir el contador `c`, pero en realidad tal como lo has escrito sigue sin resolverse nada.

**Primer problema**, sigues usando `for x in lista` y posteriormente `lista[x]`, cuando deberías estar usando en este caso `lista[c]`.

**Segundo problema** has incluido un `if c > 0` quizás con la intención de saltarte la última iteración, pero lo cierto es que lo que te estás saltando es la primera.

### Solución

Como he dicho una solución es iterar por `range(4)`, pero eso causa problema con el último elemento. La solución es obvia, y consiste en iterar una vez menos, es decir `range(3)` para evitar acceder a un elemento más allá del final.

Sería por tanto:

```
lista=[3,2,5,9]
for x in range(len(lista)-1):
    if lista[x] > lista[x+1]: 
       print(x)
```

En realidad no estoy seguro de si en el `print()` pretendes mostrar el valor de `x` (que sería el índice en el que se cumple que un elemento es mayor que el siguiente y que en tu caso arrojaría por pantalla `0`, ya que solo el primer elemento es mayor que el siguiente), o bien el valor del elemento que lo cumpla (es decir 3 en este ejemplo). Si se trata de lo segundo debes imprimir `lista[x]`.

### Otra solución

Que podría considerarse más pythónica es, en lugar de iterar por los índices, iterar por los valores. Pero en ese caso ¿cómo sacar el siguiente?

Un truco es juntar tu lista original `lista`, con esta otra: `lista[1:]` que es tu lista excepto el primer elemento (sale así una lista más corta). Ambas listas se juntan con `zip()` así: `zip(lista, lista[1:])`

La función `zip()` va retornando parejas, un dato de cada lista. En este caso retornará las parejas (3,2), (2,5), (5,9) y ahí se detendrá porque una de las listas se agotó.

Así que podemos escribir:

```
lista=[3,2,5,9]
for v1, v2 in zip(lista, lista[1:]):
    if v1 > v2:
       print(v1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es usar `enumerate` que es muy usado en Python cuando necesitas indizar una lista.

La función `enumerate` transforma una lista en un iterable que devuelte tuplas con la posición del elemento y dicho elemento. Puedes ver más sobre esta función en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
lista=[3,2,5,9]

for indice, elemento in enumerate(lista[:-1]):
    if elemento > lista[indice+1]:
        print(elemento)
```

**Salida:** `3`

Lo único que tenemos que hacer es no selecionar en el bucle `for` el último elemento de la lista, por ello hacemos `enumerate(lista[:-1])`